# warning C4996 at vs 2013

Tags: visual-c++

Good morning! I read your response to some previous question ::

to warning C4996
at vs 2010, especially at vs 2012.
you have to put the the following code at the top of the file

## define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

And set the precompiled header option to "not using" at the project's property page.

share|improve this answer
edited Nov 29 '13 at 9:25

answered Dec 30 '12 at 9:43 d""

I know this was a while back, but I am getting this error a lot, and I am attempting to include your reply to my file.
I'm just not sure how to write it in my code, as I am trying to use Visual Studio Express 2013

this is the only error at this point...

Tish

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you would give us a link to the other thread.
And what´s the problem ith just writing

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

in your file, above the `#include`´s?